# nmake compilation error for GitHub program

Tags: windows, github, makefile, terminal, nmake

I know next to nothing about Microsoft.
I'm trying to use [this program](https://github.com/iris-edu/mseed2ascii) in Windows. I opened a Development Command Prompt Window and wrote on the command line: nmake -f Makefile.win, but it didn't work. There are some compiling errors but I don't know what they mean. Does someone know how to solve this?

```
    link.exe /nologo /out:..\mseed2ascii.exe ..\libmseed\libmseed.lib mseed2ascii.obj
mseed2ascii.obj : error LNK2019: símbolo externo _zs_init sin resolver al que se hace referencia en la función _main
mseed2ascii.obj : error LNK2019: símbolo externo _zs_free sin resolver al que se hace referencia en la función _main
mseed2ascii.obj : error LNK2019: símbolo externo _zs_entrybegin sin resolver al que se hace referencia en la función _writeascii
mseed2ascii.obj : error LNK2019: símbolo externo _zs_entrydata sin resolver al que se hace referencia en la función _writedata
mseed2ascii.obj : error LNK2019: símbolo externo _zs_entryend sin resolver al que se hace referencia en la función _writeascii
mseed2ascii.obj : error LNK2019: símbolo externo _zs_finish sin resolver al que se hace referencia en la función _main
..\mseed2ascii.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 6 externos sin resolver
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX86\x86\link.exe"' : código devuelto '0x460'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.EXE"' : código devuelto '0x2'
Stop.
```

Comment: The Spanish diagnostic messages are a bit of a challenge for me, but they appear to be link errors: the linker is complaining that several of the functions in the program contain calls to other functions that are not included in any of the objects being linked.  The English text of such messages typically contains something along the lines of "unresolved reference to", and you might find that a useful search term, including here on SO.

Comment: We have absolutely no way to pinpoint the specific issue, however, because it depends on details of the program source and the nmake input file.  We would need a [mre] to make any headway.